# How do I display media, URL's or PDF links with WordPress custom fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, media, custom-fields

I am running WordPress 4.5.2, Twentysixteen, and a plugin called 'Custom Fields Template'. I am looking to make the most of WordPress' custom fields but do not know how to make it do more than display a UL with some basic text data.

I would like to know how to:

- display an image (from Media Library),
- an active link, and
- an active link to a media file *(e.g. Download PDF Brochure)*.

I like the 'Custom Fields Template' plugin as it was super easy to install, set up with the variables I need, is clean and lightweight. Here are some screenshots of what I've got so far (for a racehorse syndication website - not live):

[This is the Custom Fields Template within WordPress' page edit screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su4GW.jpg)

[This is the resulting code - prints image ID only.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMfEA.jpg)

I am comfortable with modifying WordPress's .php files but am not fluent enough with PHP to write the necessary functions from scratch.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The screenshots are pretty useless ... please add the relevant php code to your question.

Comment: Hi Gerald, I don't have a lot of existing php to offer. As mentioned, I'm running WordPress' standard Twentysixteen theme and am experimenting with it's custom fields. So this theme has existing support for one simple line as follows: the_meta();
This one line of .php takes the custom fields and simply presents them as a plain text UL. I'm assuming I need to somehow expand on that line to include extra functions. E.g. Identify page number, identify attachments and present them as active/clickable/etc. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just come across this very helpful article for beginners - it broke down the steps I needed to take to achieve what I was after:
https://perishablepress.com/wordpress-custom-fields-tutorial/

This is the Download & Print Brochure link I ended up with (using any custom field data i.e. with and without the plugin).

```
<?php $imageid = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Brochure', true); ?>
<a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $imageid ); ?>" target="_blank">Download &amp; Print Brochure</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide enough specifics I can only write a very generic answer.

The function [`the_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/the_meta) you found does not belong to the theme, it is provided by the WordPress core and as you already noticed is not very customizable, it's output can only be styled with CSS.

I assume this is the plugin you are using: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-field-template/
Based on that assumption you have these possibilities:

The plugin provides the shortcode `[cft]` you can use in the content of the post itself. It's usage is described a little bit in the plugin description, but not much.

If know that you want to show this on every post or every certain post type you can create a template file for this and call the shortcode directly using [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/).

```
echo do_shortcode( "[cft]" );
```

If you don't like the output of that shortcode either, you can [address the custom fields directly](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

It looks like the plugin doesn't show you the field names it actually uses, so you need to find them yourself. You can do this either by looking at the database, you'll find them in the table `wp_postmeta`, or you add some debug output to your template file, like this:

```
$meta = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
var_dump( $meta );
```

This will show you all custom fields from the current post. You can then either use this array to print your values, or you use [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) to retrieve specific field values.

Last, but not least: You stated that you are using the default theme Twentysixteen. You should NOT edit any of these theme files, or the files from the custom field plugin. The next time they are updated all your changes are going to be lost. Instead, [create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and add your post templates there.

Comment: Thanks Gerald - sorry for not being very specific but you've helped me in a big way just pointing me in the right direction. IDing the meta tags should make it a lot easier for me to tell them what I want them to do!